# UITabbarController delegate not calling?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

Hi I am developing a `UITabBar` application.

I need:

1.When I select a `TabBAr` item I need to get the current selected index.

2.Based on the current index I want to perform some action in `AppDelegate`.

3.So is there a any delegate methods which called whenever I pressed the tab bar items.

4.Please suggest some way to check in `AppDelegate` every time I presses Tab Items

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google:

```
- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
```

Make sure to link the delegate in IB...

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can using this delegate method

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    NSLog(@"selected index : %i",[tabBarController selectedIndex]);

    }
```

this method called whenever you touch any of TabBarItem.

Answer (score 0):

First set the delegate Protocol e.g UITabBarControllerDelegate and then
put self.tabbarcontroller.delegate = self; in your ViewDidLoad or somewhere where the object get's initialized